# Comparar fechas en php

Tags: php

Por qué no me funciona este ejemplo:

```
$fecha = new \DateTime("2016-05-17 0:0:0");
$fechaCounter = clone $fecha;
$fechaLimite = clone $fecha;

while ($fechaCounter <= $fechaLimite->add(new \DateInterval("P2D"))) {
    echo "hola mundo";
    $fechaCounter->add(new \DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

En lugar de imprimir 2 veces hola mundo causa un bucle infinito.

Gracias anticipadas.
Un saludo

Editado:

Así si funciona:

```
$fecha = new \DateTime("2016-05-17 0:0:0");
$fechaCounter = clone $fecha;
$fechaLimite = clone $fecha;
$fechaLimite->add(new \DateInterval("P2D"));
echo $fechaLimite->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");
while ($fechaCounter <= $fechaLimite) {
    echo $fechaCounter->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")."\n";
    $fechaCounter->add(new \DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que al ejecutar

```
$fechaLimite->add(new \DateInterval("P2D"))
```

Se modifica cada vez `$fechaLimite`. Si miramos el manual vemos que `add` modifica el objeto `Date`: http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php

Hay que tener cuidado en cada función u objeto para saber si las funciones tratan a los objetos como mutables o inmutables (o sea si los modifican o no). Eso cambia para cada lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código usando [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php):

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41fd23bcc2588d39ee64db4afc0a9fc51c78add8)**

```
$fechaHoy = new DateTime("2016-05-17 00:00:00");
$fechaLimite = clone $fechaHoy;    
$fechaLimite->add(new DateInterval("P2D"));

// Calcula la diferencia y devuelve el resultado
echo = $fechaHoy->diff($fechaLimite)->format('%a'); // 2
```